# Open an html file in another page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the open a new window in javascript. I have done this using the window.open() function.
As seen here

```
   var opened = window.open("");
   opened.document.write("<p>helloWorld</p>");
```

Instead of writing my html code as an argument in the opened.document.write() function could I make the function open an html file.

Comment: Yes, you can just put the url in the first parameter, didn't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If the html is static,you just host it on your webserver at a different path.

Then you would only need to use `window.open("/path/to/html/file.html")`

here is more info on using window.open()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Thank you for your help I'm new to all of this so getting an easy straight answer on this site is very nice.